# Error con excepciones java

Tags: java, excepciones

Tengo este código de java sobre excepciones.

Quiero crear un método que valide si los argumentos que pase son correctos, sino que realice la excepción.

El problema es que esto me lleva a que agregue en el setter una excepción , y si le agrego a este, me tira que el constructor necesita excepción.

```
public class Contribuyente {
    private String sexo;

    public Contribuyente(String sexo){
        this.setSexo(sexo);
    }

    public void setSexo(String sexo) {
        validarSexo(sexo);
        this.sexo=sexo;
    }

    public static boolean validarSexo(String sexo)throws Exception {
        boolean valido=true;
        if((!"F".equals(sexo))||(!"M".equals(sexo)))
        {
            valido=false;
        }
        if (valido==false)throw new Exception("Sexo invalido");
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Si te molesta la excepcion así lanzala como RuntimeException esa no es catcheable, sin embargo no te recomiendo llamar métodos públicos desde el constructor, ya que si a tu clase la extienden y llegan a sobreescribir ese método, tendrás un comportamiento extraño.

Answer (score 1):

Para el caso de un método que solo valida dos valores no es tan práctico el uso de la Exception. Es decir el metodo validarSexo debería devolver true si es M o F y en cualquier otro caso false, sin excepciones.
Ahora bien, si lo que estás intentando es probar el uso de Exceptions y su propagación, no hay ningún problema en agregar la clausula throws Exception en el constructor. En términos prácticos esto significaría que a la hora de crear ese objeto no se aceptará ningun valor de parámetro que no sea el esperado. De manera que en tu ejemplo es necesario agregar la cláusula en el constructor y quedará bien validado.